# How to fix Inheritance problem which is not working for styleshee in flaskt

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, flask

I am trying to complete web app with python and flask. I have a "search page" and "result page". In the result page, when user clicks "isbn", it goes to "detail page". I am using inheritance in flask to generate htmls based on my "layput.html" but the problem is styles.css does not work for my detail page while it is working for other pages. Here is the terminal output (stylesheet works for authentication and search but not working for detail page);

```
     127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2019 22:06:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
     127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2019 22:06:20] "POST /authentication HTTP/1.1"    200 -
     127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2019 22:06:23] "POST /search HTTP/1.1e" 200 -
     127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2019 22:06:44] "GET /search/0375706860 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
     127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2019 22:06:44] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This is my base template "layout.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
      {% block head %}
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Custom Styles -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/styles.css">

      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates" rel="stylesheet">

      <title>BookReview</title>
      {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
          <!--Links-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <form class="" action="{{ url_for('logout') }}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="logoutButton" value="Log Out">
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid headTitle">
        <h1>Meet your next favorite book!</h1>
        <h4>See bunch of book reviews and discussions to decide what to read next.</h4>
      </div>
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is the html of detail page;

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
  <div class="container-fluid searchContainer">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Isbn</th>
          <th scope="col">Author</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Year</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ bookDetails.isbn }}</td>
          <td>{{ bookDetails.author }}</td>
          <td>{{ bookDetails.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ bookDetails.year }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a discrepancy here `ERROR 404` is a "PAGE NOT FOUND ERROR", your href link is like this in "layout.html".

```
 <!-- Custom Styles -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/styles.css">
```

```
static 
|_styles
   |_styles.css
```

BUT, in your error it shows this, `GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404` 
Which means its expecting this,

```
static
|_styles.css
```

Fix that and your error should be solved. 
Did you notice that ?

My guess is that, your styles.css is being used only in the design.html page, hence the search for styles.css is throwing an error because location not found.